# Java EE 6 @Startup and @Schedule never being executed

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb, scheduling, startup

I have the following singleton which should be executed when the web application starts but it does not, and the scheduled task does not run either.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Scheduler {

    private static int count = 0;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onStartup() {
        System.out.println("Initialization success.");
    }

   @Schedule(second="*/10", minute="*", hour="*")
   public void execute() {
      System.out.println("its running count..."+count);
      count++;
   }
}
```

I am using Glassfish server 3.1.2.

**EDIT**

The startup method is now being executed but the schedule method does not run.

Comment: Can you show the import for the Singleton annotation?

Comment: Hi. it is:   import javax.ejb.Singleton;

Comment: Do you see any errors / logs from GlassFish during (re)deployment?

Comment: No errors. Nothing related to this anyway. Does the location of the singleton make a difference? I currently have it in a .util package. Struggling to find what else could be wrong.

Comment: The location doesn't matter. What logs do you see when (re)deploying? Add them to the original question with the "edit" button

Comment: I checked the logs again and this time the onStartup method showed up so this being executed just fine. Bu the schedule method does not run. Any ideas? ... just to add I have never set up the scheduling on this before so unsure how it works.

Comment: maybe my answer here applies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092567/automatic-ejb-timer-on-glassfish-server-not-triggering/13102822#13102822

Comment: Thank you Aksel. The persistent=false was the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding another answer as there was some questions on Boreded's own answer.

The reason why setting `persistence=false` solved the problem is likely due to that persistent timers are not re-created if already existing when `keepstate` is set to true.

you should see the following in the log

```
INFO: keepstate is true and will not create new auto timers during deployment.
```

I think my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092567/automatic-ejb-timer-on-glassfish-server-not-triggering/13102822#13102822) (together with Roland Tiefenbrunner's answer on same question) covers the issue somewhat well.

Comment: No. Normally, the timer is invoked with keepstate true as well as false, with persistent true as well as false.

Comment: The other answer given in the related question seems reasonable. Do you get any derby errors during GF startup?

Comment: Well sure the timer still fires, but what I think happens here is that first a timer without trace is deployed. So when you later change your timer to include the output-trace, it is not deployed. Changing keep-state or making the timer non-persistent redeployes the new timer.

Answer (score 11):

My problem was that I used the wrong `Singleton` class, not `javax.inject.Singleton` but `javax.ejb.Singleton`

Comment: I had exactly the same problem right now, it was driving me nuts until I realized that the wrong Singleton annotation was imported.

Comment: Which of the two classes should it be?

Comment: I agree Peter, it's hard to tell from the comment!

Comment: This was my error as well. For a complete explanation of how to create a scheduler using a singleton in Java EE/Jarkata EE see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7499769/1090666. Just make sure that when you do, you import the correct Singleton class.

Comment: I was having the same issue. You must use `javax.ejb.Singleton` and `javax.ejb.Startup` for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Also watch out for the default values of the annotation.  Hour, minute and second default to 0 NOT *, whereas the others default to * , so e.g. @Schedule(minute = "*/20", persistent = false) will only fire at 20 + 40 mins past midnight.

```
@Target(value=METHOD)
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
public @interface Schedule {
   String dayOfMonth() default "*";

   String dayOfWeek() default "*";

   String hour() default "0";

   String info() default "";

   String minute() default "0";

   String month() default "*";

   boolean persistent() default true;

   String second() default "0";

   String timezone() default "";

   String year() default "*";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure it out, but reading your answer just makes sense and fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else with a similar issue adding the following fixed my problem:

```
persistent=false
```

So my schedule annotation is now

```
@Schedule(second="*/10", minute="*", hour="*", persistent=false)
```

Comment: The code exposed in the question works well without putting persistence=false. If this solution really solves the problem, it is accidentally hiding your real problem